# Heroku deployment build failure Java Spring project : package java.net.http does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I have been trying to deploy a java spring project on Heroku but I keep getting this error. The project is a tracker that uses some data from an online csv file and displays data using the information. It also updates the information daily. when I host it locally using http://localhost:8080/ it works fine. Here is the error message.

```
       [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 

       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[15,21] package java.net.http does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[16,21] package java.net.http does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[17,21] package java.net.http does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[46,9] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   class HttpClient

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[46,29] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   variable HttpClient

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[47,9] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   class HttpClient

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[47,30] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   variable HttpClient

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[48,9] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   class HttpRequest

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[48,30] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   variable HttpRequest

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[49,9] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   class HttpRequest

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[49,31] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   variable HttpRequest

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[51,9] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   class HttpResponse

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[51,76] package HttpResponse does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[52,9] cannot find symbol

         symbol:   class HttpResponse

         location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[52,78] package HttpResponse does not exist

       [INFO] 15 errors 

       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE

       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

       [INFO] Total time:  12.179 s

       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-20T05:56:34Z

       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Corona-Track: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[15,21] package java.net.http does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[16,21] package java.net.http does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[17,21] package java.net.http does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[46,9] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpClient

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[46,29] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   variable HttpClient

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[47,9] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpClient

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[47,30] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   variable HttpClient

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[48,9] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpRequest

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[48,30] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   variable HttpRequest

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[49,9] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpRequest

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[49,31] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   variable HttpRequest

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[51,9] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpResponse

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[51,76] package HttpResponse does not exist

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[52,9] cannot find symbol

       [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpResponse

       [ERROR]   location: class com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services.CoronaDataService

       [ERROR] /tmp/build_764c076e_/src/main/java/com/Corona/CoronaTrack/services/CoronaDataService.java:[52,78] package HttpResponse does not exist

       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

       [ERROR] 

       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

       [ERROR] 

       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven

       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,

       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.

 !     Push failed
```

Here is the location it keeps saying there is a problem

```
package com.Corona.CoronaTrack.services;


import com.Corona.CoronaTrack.models.Stats;
import com.Corona.CoronaTrack.models.Stats2;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CoronaDataService {

    private static String VirusDataURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv";
    private static String VirusDataURL2= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us.csv";

    private List<Stats> allStats = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Stats> getAllStats() {
        return allStats;
    }

    private List<Stats2> allStats2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Stats2> getAllStats2() {
        return allStats2;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Scheduled(cron = "* * 1 * * *")
    public void GetCornonaData() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<Stats> newStats = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Stats2> newStats2 = new ArrayList<>();


        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpClient client2 = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request= HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(VirusDataURL)).build();
        HttpRequest request2= HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(VirusDataURL2)).build();

        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse=client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse2=client.send(request2, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        StringReader  csvBody2 = new StringReader(httpResponse2.body());
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records2 = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(csvBody2);
        for (CSVRecord record2 : records2) {
            Stats2 locationStat2 = new Stats2();
            
            locationStat2.setTotalAmountOfCases(record2.get(record2.size()-2));

            
            locationStat2.setTotalAmountOfDeaths(record2.get(record2.size()-1));
           
            newStats2.add(locationStat2);
        }
        this.allStats2 = newStats2;


        StringReader  csvBody = new StringReader(httpResponse.body());
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(csvBody);
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            Stats locationStat = new Stats();
            locationStat.setDate(record.get("date"));
            locationStat.setState(record.get("state"));
            locationStat.setCases(record.get("cases"));
            locationStat.setDeaths(record.get("deaths"));
            newStats.add(locationStat);
        }
        this.allStats = newStats;
    }
}
```

I know it’s not the best code ever. This is my first project using spring. If you have any suggestions on a better way to deploy my project I would appreciate the advice. I appreciate any help given and thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`java.net.http` has been introduced in Java 11 which you probably use locally.

Heroku by default provides a Java 8 runtime, you can however set your desired Java version. Create a file `system.properties` in the root of your project which contains:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked I greatly appreciate you the help.